MS Visual Studio 2022 not able to open source files with path length more than 120 characters
While building a project on the MS visual studio 2022. I'm getting the following error:
Error   C1083   Cannot open source file: '..\..\..\..\Source\Application-Protocols\network_transport\tcp_sockets_wrapper\ports\freertos_plus_tcp\tcp_sockets_wrapper.c': No such file or director

If I rename file/folder names to make the length of the path less than or equal to 120 (current length is 124), the error goes away and the project is built successfully.
I think this might be due to a setting that disallows paths greater than particular length, but I'm not sure where to update that.
VS project


Open the Registry Editor (regedit).
Navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem.
Create a new DWORD (32-bit) value named LongPathsEnabled and set its value to 1.
Restart your computer.

